# Lumen JWT Auth always return 401 in other route after login success

Tags: api, routes, jwt, lumen, unauthorized

I have lumen + jwt restapi with custom users table (ex : pengguna) with nomor as primary key and tgl_lahir as password..there is no problem with api/login and it's generate a token but when i try with other route such as api/buku, the return always 401 unauthorized although the authorization header contains valid token after login

my models like

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, JWTSubject
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable;
    protected $primaryKey = 'nomor';
    protected $table = 'pengguna';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'nomor','nama','alamat'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'tgl_lahir ',
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

my BukuController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Buku;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class BukuController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    
    public function showAllBuku()
    {
        return response()->json(Buku::all());
    }

}
```

my routes

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    $router->get('buku',  ['uses' => 'BukuController@showAllBuku']);
});
```

config/auth.php

```
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => \App\User::class
        ]
    ],
];
```

the existing pengguna table don't allowed created ID field like lumen/laravel auth, if i commented code in Middleware\Authenticate like :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        
//if this block commented is working
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

it's working..is there another way for my case?thanks for your help

Comment: sorry my mistake, my problem solved by add this in user model -> public function getAuthIdentifierName(){
        return $this->nomor;
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->{$this->getAuthIdentifierName()};
    }

Comment: You can add your answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

sorry my mistake, my problem solved by add this in user model

```
public function getAuthIdentifierName(){ 
return $this->nomor; 
} 

public function getAuthIdentifier(){ 
return $this->{$this->getAuthIdentifierName()}; 
}
```